# Let or Var in modern javascript?

Tags: javascript

"`Let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the `var` keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Which one should be used in modern javascript code? `let` or `var`?

Edit: 
I checked the Google JavaScript Style Guide and it states "Declarations with var: Always" (https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml)

But in the tutorial at javascript.info (not sure if this is an official JavaScript website or not) it says to use `let` (https://javascript.info/variables)

I'm assuming I should stick to what Google recommends, but am still open to answers.

Second Edit: The above is not the most recent Google JavaScript Style Guide. In that one it states: "Declare all local variables with either `const` or `let`. Use `const` by default, unless a variable needs to be reassigned. The `var` keyword must not be used".(https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-local-variable-declarations)

Comment: Whichever one makes sense for your own code. Usually it's better to scope variables as locally as possible, except when it isn't.

Comment: Your referenced style guide is out of date. https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-local-variable-declarations   - the problem isn't so much good practice as, it depends on what platform your building for. Many people require IE11 and below. ES6 still isn't particularly friendly.

Answer (score 7):

In modern JS, use `let` or `const` whenever possible and appropriate. The semantics match more closely those how variables and constants work in other programming languages, and you'll avoid a lot of cognitive overhead caused by all the peculiarities that `var` has, compared to other languages (such as hoisting).